# testng reporter.log treats "<" as "["

Tags: java, html, testng

I'm trying to add screenshots to my testng report but the html "pointy brackets" are logged as square brackets so the report looks like the following. Anyone else experiencing this problem?

My Code:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(filename));
Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(testResult);
Reporter.log("<a href=\"" + filename + "\">Screenshot</a>");
```

Generated Report:

```
[a href="filename.png"]Screenshot[/a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue:
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/commit/6a577ffe7ea59c27434829ae3f11f0074b1d7cf5

Comment: Thanks! I'll track the issue and report back.

Comment: There's been an issue created for this as well, https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/250

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. Try to update testng plugin (http://testng.org/doc/download.html) and put the line -Dorg.uncommons.reportng.escape-output=off  into Run->Run Configurations->(x)=Arguments in field VW arguments.